# Why do other JavaScript files not work in my PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eimx3.png) I work with Laravel(last version) and Vue 2. When I include default app.js (the only js files that work) in my file.blade.php page it work. But if I create a other js file example: apple.js in the same path than app.js (ressource/js/app.js),it doesn't want to find it.

Console google chrome : GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/apple.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

What I have already tried:

```
script src="{{URL::asset('/js/apple.js')}}" /script
```

AND

```
script src="{{asset('/js/apple.js')}}" /script
```

AND

```
script src="/js/apple.js" /script
```

AND FINALLY

```
script src="js/apple.js" /script
```

I take off quote for display purpose.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.css">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">


    <style>

        body { padding-top:40px; }

    </style>


</head>
<body>





<div id="something" class="container">


    <tabs>

        <tab name="About us"  :selected="true">

            <h1>Here is the content for theabout us tab</h1>

        </tab>


        <tab name="About our Culture">

            <h1>Here is the content for the about our culture tab</h1>

        </tab>


        <tab name="About Our Vision">

            <h1>Here is the content for the about our vision tab</h1>

        </tab>

    </tabs>



</div>






<script src="{{asset('/js/apple.js')}}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: URL::asset searches files in public folder. Do your files get compiled or copied in public js folder?

Comment: Yes I did that. I have a compiled apple.js file in public/js. And I have a apple.js file in ressources/js .

Comment: can you post the snapshot of your `chrome inspect element`? Sometime it might be the directory permission issue with chrome.

Comment: have you tried `src="{{asset('js/apple.js')}}"` and also `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Yes I tried, it does not work either. When I include app.js(Work), the Vue tool on Chrome is open. But when I include apple.js (doesnt work) , the Vue tool on window is close. So I think the problem is with Vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change directory structure *`resource/js/apple.js`* to *`public/js/apple.js`*

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/apple.js') }}"></script>
```

This will work if your directory structure is like this: */public/js/apple.js*

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it happens due to we forget to compile the file.
Make sure you compile the file and it appears in public folder. 
For compilation, run command:
      `npm run dev`

For continuous compilation, run `watch` command:
     `npm run watch`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this if you are using it in blade file.

```
@section('script')
<script .....></script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Are you using laravel backpack? If yes, then try using @extends('backpack::layout') first and then @section('script')<script></script>@endsection

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a folder (name it what ever you want usually I name it js because it contains js files) inside public directory and not inside resources directory and then call the file using:
`<script type='text/javascript' src="{{ asset('/js/apple.js') }}"></script>`